# Limit of a greatest integer function (sided limit)

Tags: limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions, indeterminate-forms

> What is the value of $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \dfrac{b}{x}\left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{a}\right\rfloor$ for $a>0$ and $b>0$. Note that $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

I know that $\left\lfloor\dfrac xa\right\rfloor=0$. But when it comes to $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\dfrac bx\cdot0$, the result is indeterminate. I want to know how to remove this indetermination.

Comment: As $x\to0^+$, we have that $\lceil\frac xa\rceil\to1$. So, the limit is equivalent to $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac bx=\infty$.

Comment: @DonThousand I think YiFan is right, but at end wont comes in a indetermination?

Comment: You changed the question since I wrote the comment. My comment no longer applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sufficiently small but **positive** $x$ (in particular $0<x<a$), we have that $0<x/a<1$. This means that $\lfloor x/a\rfloor= 0$ so that the limit is just $\lim_{x\to 0^+}(b/x)\cdot0=0$.

Note that the requirement that $x$ can't be $0$ comes from the definition of a limit-- $x$ gets closer and closer to, but never equals, $0$.

Comment: Thanks mate! But please explain how [x/a] equals 1. Because if x is very small but positive, dividing x for any number >0,for example, lets take a=2, would be 0,02/2=0,01. And using greatest integer function, is goind to be =0, am I wrong?

Comment: @Math: $\lceil x\rceil$ denotes the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$. It is different from $\lfloor x\rfloor$ which denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. Which one do you intend?

Comment: I pretend ⌊x⌋ which denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to x. Sorry, I think the site just edit the answer :/

Comment: @Math: I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing.  lim x→0+ (b/x)⋅0 isn`t a indetermination? Because when use limit product rule is going be infinite times zero, and this is a indetermination right?

Comment: " lim x→0+ (b/x)⋅0 isn`t a indetermination?" No, because $\frac bx *0 = 0$. We dont always break up $\lim f(x)g(x)$ as $\lim f(x)\cdot \lim g(x)$.  And this is a perfect example of when and why we don't  $\lim f(x)\cdot 0 = \lim 0 = 0$ because $f(x)\cdot 0 = 0$ and it doesnt matter at all what $f(x)$ does.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{b}{x}\left \lfloor{\frac{x}{a}}\right \rfloor=0,\forall x\in (0,a)$, it follows that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{b}{x}\left \lfloor{\frac{x}{a}}\right \rfloor=0$ .

Comment: +1, but I have a couple of small points. First, the question says that $a,b \gt 0$, so you don't need to say "Let $a,b \gt 0$. Thus, you can remove your first sentence, or change it to something like "Since $a,b \gt 0$ & merge it with the rest. Also, when you're dealing with limits, only values in a small enough neighborhood of the limit point (when the limit is going to a finite value instead of $\infty$) that have relevance for determining the limit value, if any, need to be considered. Thus, you don't need your next sentences, with just your last $2$ sentences being sufficient.

Comment: It's true that stabilish an upper bound is irrelevant to the question. I thought the asker was worried with the limit being infinity or zero though. It was the way I thought the problem: it cannot be infinity, so it is probably zero, and then I constructed the argument. I will edit my answer.